# Gnuplot columnstacked histogram - line/row count

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have a data file with an undefined number of entries that looks like this:

```
A B C D E..
1 0 2 5 4
7 4 3 4 1
8   7 4 0
7     1 1
```

First row represents working time, than pause and so on in alternating fashion. To visualise this, I plot a columnstacked histograms from it by defining two linestyles with different colours and plotting it via:

```
plot for [i=1:10] 'data.log' using i notitle
```

**But the problem is:** I have to guess the max value of i. How can I get the number of columns the data file has? 
And when defining the alternating linestyles I need to estimate the max number of lines in order to overwrite the default linestyles for what i use a similar for-loop:

```
set for [j = 1:1000:2] style line i lc rgb "white"
set for [j = 2:1000:2] style line i lc rgb "red"
```

Here I need to set the max number lines a column in my data has as the max value for j.

Is there a way to grab these values? Possibly by using built-in features of gnuplot only (for I am not familiar with awk scripting).

Thanks for reading,
best regards

PS: I'm using Windows

Comment: Partial answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13381311/748858

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the number of columns and rows of your datafile like this:

```
rows = `awk 'END {print NR}' data.log`
columns = `awk '{if(NR == 1) print NF}' data.log`
print "The maximum number of rows is ", rows, " and the maximum number of columns is ", columns
plot for [i=1:columns] 'data.log' using i notitle
```

You can achieve the same result without using `awk` with this approach

```
rows = `cat data.log | wc -l`
columns = `head data.log -n1 | wc -w`
```

Comment: Thanks, updated the post. Is there a solution without awk scripting? Don't want to dig in awk additionaly if I can avoid it.

Comment: Alright, I see. You suggest to leave the gnuplot script and run some linux commands. My bad I didn't mention I'm on a Windows machine. Any ideas how to achieve this within gnuplot functionality?

Comment: Sorry AFAIK gnuplot does not support this functionality.