# Count columns in csv in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a function in gnuplot which returns the number of columns in a csv file?
I can't find anything in the docs, maybe someone can propose a custom made function for this?

Comment: I don't think Gnuplot has any variable that tells you this. You  could use the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308602/gnuplot-columnstacked-histogram-line-row-count) as a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of gnuplot4.6, you can make a little hack script to do this.  It is certainly not the most efficient, but it is pure gnuplot:

```
#script col_counter.gp
col_count=1
good_data=1
while (good_data){
   stats "$0" u (valid(col_count))
   if ( STATS_max ){
      col_count = col_count+1
   } else {
      col_count = col_count-1
      good_data = 0
   }
}
```

Now in your main script,

```
call "col_counter.gp" "my_datafile_name"
print col_count   #number of columns is stored in col_count.
```

This has some limitations -- It will choke if you have a column in the datafile that is completely non-numeric followed by more valid columns for example, but I think that it should work for many typical use cases.

```
print col_count
```

As a final note, you can use the environment variable `GNUPLOT_LIB` and then you don't even need to have `col_counter.gp` in the current directory.

Comment: I borrowed your idea for my answer here: [accessing the nth datapoint in a datafile using gnuplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986596/accessing-the-nth-datapoint-in-a-datafile-using-gnuplot/17416567#17416567)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13371449/1331399), and that the content of *infile.csv* is:

```
n,John Smith stats,Sam Williams stats,Joe Jackson stats
1,23.4,44.1,35.1 
2,32.1,33.5,38.5 
3,42.0,42.1,42.1
```

You could do it like this:

*plot.gp*

```gnuplot
nc = "`awk -F, 'NR == 1 { print NF; exit }' infile.csv`"
set key autotitle columnhead
set datafile separator ','
plot for [i=2:nc] "< sed -r '1 s/,([^ ]+)[^,]+/,\\1/g' infile.csv" using 1:i with lines
```

Note that the `\1` needs escaping when used within `"` in Gnuplot.

Output:

[image: Data file plot]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update and an alternative extended retro-workaround: (of course *gnuplot-only*)

**Update:** (gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan 2015)

Since gnuplot 5.0.0, there is the variable `STATS_columns` which will tell you the number of columns of the **first unommented** row.

```
stats FILE u 0 nooutput
print STATS_columns
```

**Extended retro-workaround:** (gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

Some time ago, I [learnt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55188544/7295599) that a correct CSV file should have the same number of columns (i.e. commas) in all rows. So it should be sufficient to "count" the commas in the first uncommented row. That's apparently what gnuplot>=5.0.0 is doing more or less.

However, in case you have an "incorrect CSV" with varying columns and you are interested in the minimum and maximum number of columns, you can use the following script, assuming that there are no (doublequoted) strings having a comma inside. Note, row indices are 0-based.

**Data:** `SO13373206.dat`

```
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46
```

**Script:**

```
### count number of columns (gnuplot>=4.6.0)
reset

FILE = "SO13373206.dat"

countCommas(s) = sum[i=1:strlen(s)] ( s[i:i] eq ',' ? 1 : 0)
set datafile separator "\t"         # in order to read a row as one string
stats FILE u (colCount=countCommas(strcol(1))+1,0) every ::0::0 nooutput
print sprintf("number of columns in first row: %d", colCount)

colMin = colMax = rMin = rMax = NaN
stats FILE u (c=countCommas(strcol(1))+1, \
              c<colMin || colMin!=colMin ? (colMin=c,rMin=$0) : 0, \
              c>colMax || colMax!=colMax ? (colMax=c,rMax=$0) : 0 ) nooutput
print sprintf("minimum %d columns in row %d",colMin, rMin)
print sprintf("maximum %d columns in row %d",colMax, rMax)

set datafile separator ","    # restore separator
# ... plot something
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
number of columns in first row: 7
minimum 6 columns in row 3
maximum 9 columns in row 2
```