# accessing the nth datapoint in a datafile using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

After searching through all pipes to and inbuilt functions in gnuplot, I still haven't found a simple way to access the nth element of my datafile (not through increment, the single value) for use as a constant in a function (or parameter in a for loop) for my plots. For example I have a monotonic decreasing datafile with two columns and I want to normalize the y values while plotting so the y ranges from one (1) to zero (0) by subtracting the last value from each datapoint and dividing the subtraction by the difference between the first datapoint and the last. I tried awk but I'm not too familiar with the syntax.  If there is a simple way I would love to know.

For example

plot "my2columndata.dat" using 1:(($2-'lastdatapoint')/('firstdatapoint'-'lastdatapoint'))

or something of the sorts where first and last datapoints are eponymous - they are the first and last datapoints in the monotonic decreasing datafile "my2columndata.dat"

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provided sample input and expected output.

Comment: ok sorry about the ambiguity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case (since you know that the datafile is monotonically decreasing), this isn't too hard to do.

```
set terminal unknown
plot 'my2columndata.dat' # gather basic statistics
first=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
last=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN

set terminal <whatever>
set output <whatever.wht>
plot 'my2columndata.dat' u 1:(($2-last)/(first-last))
```

This method gathers information about the datafile without creating an output, then replots using the GPVAL variables.  (You can see this in gnuplot after plotting with the command `show variables all`.)  In gnuplot 4.6.0 and above you can use the `stats` command to gather data without plotting as I have done here; `stats` creates different variable names though.

Accessing the n-th data point (as your question title hinted) would be trickier to do.

Comment: Thanks! This suits me perfectly and is simple I am curious to know how you could index the individual numbers but this certainly works! I'm reading up on similar commands.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is the same as @andyras 's, but using `stats`.

To answer the title, you can use `every ::n::n`, where n is the record (i.e. datapoint) number of choice. Records are numbered from 0, so if you want the first line, it should be `every ::0::0`. `every` can be used in either `plot`, `splot`, or `stats` (usage of `every` in `stats` is undocumented). I prefer `stats` since it doesn't plot anything, but it does clutter your gnuplot console (*EDIT* to avoid the cluttered console use `nooutput` at the end of the `stats` command). Also, you can use `using` to make arbitrary assingments.

For example, to save the second column of your first record,

```
stats "my2columndata.dat" u (firstdatapoint=$2) every ::0::0
```

Now to get the last record, you can use the number of records saved by `stats`, and use that as the record number in `every`,

```
stats "my2columndata.dat" # this saves the number of records to STATS_records
stats "my2columndata.dat" u (lastdatapoint=$2) every ::STATS_records-1::STATS_records-1
```

Now you can do the plot that you asked for.

---

And before I finish, some extra hacks:

Using [mgilson's idea of counting columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373206/count-columns-in-csv-in-gnuplot), you can even save every column to a number of variables. (Note: I'm using shorthands `u` for `using`, and `ev` for `every`)

```
filename = "yourfilename.dat"
r = 0 # record number
good = 1
col = 1
while (good) {
 stats filename u (good=valid(col)) ev ::r::r
 if (good) {
  stats filename u col ev ::r::r
  eval(sprintf("v%d=STATS_max",col))
  col = col+1
 }
}
```

If the datafile contains 8 columns, then `v1` to `v8` are now defined.

But I suppose using an external tool is the right way to it (UNIX-likes can use tail/head etc.). Let's blame gnuplot authors for making this possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is pretty old, in some cases it still might be necessary to get the first, nth or last value of a certain column. I know, that Linux users might use awk or other external programs, but the following is a platform independent *gnuplot-only* solution.

The difference of this solution to the existing answers from @andyras and @syockit:

- works also for non-monotonically decreasing data
- doesn't need `stats`
- will also work with data having several empty lines (@syockit's solution might give wrong results)
- returns also the `n`th data point.

Works also with gnuplot 4.6.0 (the time of OPs question).

**Data:** (`"Data.dat"`)

```
# some comments
 0.1  0.2
 1.1  1.2
 2.1  2.2

 4.1  4.2
 5.1  5.2

 7.1  7.2


10.1 10.2
11.1 11.2

13.1 13.2
14.1 14.2


17.1 17.2

19.1 19.2
20.1 20.2

22.1 22.2

24.1 24.2
25.1 25.2
```

**Code:**

```
### get fist, nth and last datapoint of a column
reset

PointFirst = NaN
PointNth = NaN
PointLast = NaN
N=8

set terminal unknown
n=0
plot "Data.dat" u (n=n+1, n==1?PointFirst=$2:NaN, N==n?PointNth=$2:PointLast=$2)

print sprintf("First point:  %g",PointFirst)
print sprintf("% 2dth point:  %g",N,PointNth)
print sprintf("Last point:  %g",PointLast)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
First point:  0.2
 8th point:  11.2
Last point:  25.2
```