# how to draw a mask (pattern fill) over a 2D plot with image - gnuplot

Tags: 2d, gnuplot

I have a text file with data of the style:

```
0 0 123
0 1 1345
. . .
x(int) y(int) intensity(double)
. . .
0 max size y 1345
1 0 564
. . .
max size x max size y intensity last point
```

this data represents a 2D map of a substance diffusing on it which I can draw with colours just by using 1:2:3 w image command like:

```
plot data.dat u ($1):($2):3 w image
```

My problem now is: I also know the boundary conditions of my 2D plane, this is, not every square of the 2D plane is available to the substance diffuse and, although I know in these areas the intensity will be 0, I would like to draw these areas with a pattern fill. For knowing these regions I have another file with:

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
. . .
x(int) y(int) value
. . .
0 max size y 0
1 0 0
. . .
max size x max size y value last point
```

where value is 0 if it is an accessible region or 1 if it is not. How would you draw this part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a very "efficient" solution, nevertheless in order to fill the mask with a pattern, one could process the corresponding file and place a rectangle at every coordinate marked as "accessible".

The script below first determines the number of records in the mask file via the `stats` command, processes this file in a loop and in each iteration [extracts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17416567/5351549) the corresponding row. If the value in the third column (saved into the variable `z`) is equal to 1, it produces an elementary rectangle at the corresponding position.

```
fName = 'mask.dat'
stats fName nooutput

unset key
set size ratio -1
set xtics out nomirror
set ytics out nomirror

w = 1.
h = 1.
set xr [STATS_min_x-w/2:STATS_max_x+w/2]
set yr [STATS_min_y-h/2:STATS_max_y+h/2]

#unset colorbox

do for [i=0:STATS_records-1] {
    stats fName using (x=$1, y=$2, z=$3) every ::i::i nooutput
    if(z == 1){
        set object \
            rectangle \
            center x,y \
            size w,h \
            fc rgb 'red' \
            fs transparent pattern 4 \
            noborder \
            front
    }
}

set palette defined (0 "black", 1 "white")
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3 w image
```

With random data (generated on a 20x20 grid), this produces:
[image]

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about drawing boxes so don't worry! I wasn't sure how to do it. Thank you very much :)