# Automatic series in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have input like:

```
year   s1   s2  s3
2000   1    2   3 
2001   2    4   6 
2002   4    8   12
```

I don't know how many series. Today it's 3, tomorrow it may be 4.

I want to plot it in a multi-series chart. Something like this:

```
set key autotitle columnhead
plot 'data/chart-year-subreddit-count' using 1:2 with lines, \
'data/chart-year-subreddit-count' using 1:3 with lines, \
'data/chart-year-subreddit-count' using 1:4 with lines
```

Except since I don't know how many columns, I don't know what to put in my gnuplot script.

Do I have to write a script to write the file? Or can gnuplot work out how many series there are automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot itself cannot count the number of columns, but you can use e.g. `wc` and `head` to count the number of columns:

```
file = 'data/chart-year-subreddit-count'
cols = int(system('head -1 '.file.' | wc -w'))
plot for [i=2:cols] file using 1:i with lines
```

Comment: That's incredible. Thanks very much. If I could give multiple updates I would.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I disagree with Christoph, since gnuplot 5.0.0 (Jan 2015) was already able to count column via `stats` and the variable `STATS_columns` (check `help stats`).

```
stats FILE u 0 nooutput
plot for [col=2:STATS_columns] FILE u 1:col
```

Even for gnuplot 4.6.0 (Mar 2012) there is a [gnuplot-only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72614673/7295599) (and hence platform-independent).

**Current versions:**

At least for gnuplot>=5.0.4 (Jul 2016) you have the following option:

```
plot for [col=2:*] FILE u 1:col
```