# Is there any reserved variable name for the last column in a data file for GNUPLOT?

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-columns

I have a data file where every row has a different number of columns. I wish to plot the 1st column VS the 3rd-last column. How do I do it?

Comment: You don't show any research effort and attempts for scripting nor give any details about your data, e.g. data separators etc. Is your problem solved? If yes, then please accept one of the answers, if not please leave a comment and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late answer, but a working *gnuplot-only* answer. You can do it without external tools to ensure platform-independence.
Since you don't give any details about your data, I assumed that there are rows with variable number of columns and the latter are separated by space.

The "trick" is to set the datafile separator to `"\n"` which will read a line as a whole.
If the data separator is space, you can split your line with `word` (check `help word`).
For each line you can determine the number of words (or "columns") via `words`.
Check the following script and result which will plot the first column versus the 3rd last column.

**Script:**

```
### plot first column vs. the 3rd last column (with variable number of columns)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  2   3   4   5
2  2   3   4   5   6   7
3  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
4  2   3   4   5   6
5  2   3   4   5   6   7   8
6  2   3   4
7  2   3   4   5   6   7
8  2   3   4   5
EOD

set datafile separator "\n"
ColFromLast(n)  = real(word(strcol(1),words(strcol(1))-n+1))
ColFromFirst(n) = real(word(strcol(1),n))

plot $Data u (ColFromFirst(1)):(ColFromLast(3)) w lp pt 7 lc "red" \
         title "Column 1 vs. 3rd from last"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always pre-process the data by passing through a filter, for example:

```
plot "<awk '{print $1 \" \" $(NF-2)}' data" using 1:2 with lines
```

The `awk` prints just columns 1 and *number of fields*-2 of file `data`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to get to the desired result within `gnuplot`:

```
# query the properties of your data file 'so.dat'; do so silently
stats 'so.dat' nooutput

# extract the number of columns and assign the value to a variable
last_col = int(STATS_columns)

# now you can do your plotting
plot 'so.dat' using 1:last_col-2
```

Comment: Does this work for rows with different number of columns?

Comment: It gives you the number of columns in the first data row. What do you need? Sample data would help.

Comment: Ah I have probably not understood your question well enough. In that case, @meuh's way is the best. If you want the third before last in every row, relative to each row, I don't see a way doing that within gnuplot.